# Add text in this PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
function woocommerce_template_product_description() {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_description', 20 );
```

This code prints a product description, but I'd like to add the text "Description:" before the description itself without having it on a separate line. How do I go about that? I am a total beginner when it comes to coding. Thanks!

Comment: This code actually loads a template. Copy the template file to your theme and edit that file.

Comment: Alright, I did find and edit the template, but still it's on two rows. My code is: 

       <?php echo "Description"; the_content(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In WordPress/WooCommerce Product are nothing but a Post. So the the product
>   description is treated as `the_content` of a post.

If you just want to add custom text/content before the Product Description then just use **`the_content` filter**.

Here is the code.

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content($content)
{
    //Only for single product page.
    if (is_product())
    {
        $prepend = 'Description';
        $content = $prepend . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content', 9); // <-- Choose some priority <
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and fully functional.

---

Reference

- [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)
- [is_product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate the template file and edit the template file, so that it renders the desired output.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

This loads a template file only
You need to edit that specific file "single-product/tabs/description.php"
and add a echo there.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

**Case-1 : Add "Description" in tab**

*Path : templates/single-product/tabs/description.php*

```
<?php echo "<b>Description</b>"; the_content(); ?>
```

**Case-2 : Add "Description" in Short description area**

*Path : templates/single-product/short-description.php*

```
<?php echo "<b>Description</b>"; ?>

<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```